# Some files (js, css, images) aren`t loading after refreshing the page in react.js

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have problem, I am using react-router for accesing full info news page by clicking link "more", everything showing and rendering fine until I change something in these 2 pages.

FullInfoNews.js

```
export  class FullInfoNews extends React.Component {
    render (){
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="about-title">
                        <div className="container">
                            <h2>{this.props.news.body}</h2>
                            <p>{this.props.news.title} </p>
                            <img className="center-block" src={this.props.news.image} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

FullInfoNewsContainer.js

```
export default class FullInfoMediaContainer extends React.Component{
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
        news:[]
    }
}

componentDidMount(){
    console.log('componentDidMount777');

    const url='http://new-sciencepark.1gb.ru/api/getNewsById/'+this.props.params.id+'?lang=Ru' ;
    superagent
        .get(url)
        .query(null)
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .end ((error, response)=>{
        const news=response.body.data.news
        console.log(JSON.stringify(news));
        this.setState({
            news: news
        })
    })
}


render(){
    console.log(this.props)
    const {params}=this.props;
    return(
        <div>
            {params.id}
            <FullInfoNews  news={this.state.news} />
        </div>

    );
}
```

}

[image]

[image]
The problem is that all the files do not load and shows 404 (not found) error. Why i do not understand? Maybe the problem with DOM?

index.html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Technopark site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/style.css">
    <script  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=visualization&key=AIzaSyD1USlQFgU5SK9iHulGnQwUEP7sB-d4Cew"></script>
    <script src="app/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

</head>
  <body>  
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="/app/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, is that the correct path to those files? What do the URLs look like when they load successfully?

Comment: yeah i am pretty sure that they are correct. Besides, it loads for the fisrt time but then when i refresh the page everything breaks up((

Comment: Can you confirm that they're the exact same URLs both when they work and when they fail? If they are, you need to look in the error logs for what goes wrong.

Comment: oh no sorry i was wrong, they are different when it succussfully loaded the path is for example <img src="app/img/logo1.png">.When it fails the path is GET http://localhost:8080/fullinfonews/app/img/logo1.png 404 (Not Found). So, it the local path should be "app/img/logo1.png

Comment: So, how i will fix it?

Comment: You need to fix the paths: instead of `app/style.css` you probably want `/app/style.css`. There may be a more react-y way to set a base path for your style sheets, but that should fix it for the moment

Comment: it worked! But why i will work just for the moment? So, it will break again after some time?

Comment: As long as your style sheets stay in that folder, it'll work. It's just that in advanced apps, it's good style to have a "base path" so that you can move your entire app into a subfolder rather than the domain root, e.g. `http://localhost/myapp/version2` rather than `http://localhost`. I'm sure React has a defined method to do that (I know only React Native so I don't know.) If you're just starting out that's probably not going to be an issue though.

Comment: ok, thank u very much! if u posted the answer I would give u a vote))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Navigating to URLs via React Router components is **NOT** the same as entering their URLs directly into the browser (which essentially what happens when you refresh a page).

That is, if you launch your app on port 5000, open the browser and go to `localhost:5000`, then click a button that pushes "/page1" to the browser history so you end up at `localhost:5000/page1`, that is **NOT** the same as opening up your browser, typing `localhost:5000/page1` into the URL bar and hitting enter. It's client-side vs server-side routing.

Can you show us you index.html?

Comment: In your index.html, change all your paths to relative ones i.e. change href="app/style.css" to href="/app/style.css" and <script src="app/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script> to <script src="/app/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script> and see if that gets rid of the 404 error on refresh for the ones you change (don't worry about the image paths in your code just yet)

Comment: Jayce444
Can you explain why adding a "forward slash" solves the issue with photos not rendering?